# Remove noise in BW image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, noise-reduction, binary-image

I used MATLAB to generate this image (using `bwareaopen`). In the middle I have a 2D ellipsoid. How can I clear all the "noise" surrounding of it and get a clear ellipsoid?

[image]

original image

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity - is this some ship at sea?

Comment: @Dev-iL Certainly does look like one...

Comment: I have some ideas, but can you provide a couple more images to test with please?

Comment: It is a cell and I added the original image. Any other idea is welcome. I have a problem to get the cell boundaries/outline due to the background color.

Comment: try using Difference of Gaussian (DoG)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this solution. As mentioned in the comments I used ***DoG - Difference of Gaussians***

**What does DoG mean ?**

First you have to take two separate Gaussians of an image with two separate kernels. (By Gaussian I mean apply ing *gaussian blur*). The difference of the two resultants is called the ***DoG***.

This is what I did:

- Converted the given umage to **gray scale**:

[image]

- Then I applied **bilateral filtering** to preserve edges and smoothen non-edges:

[image]

(If you look intently you can see the difference).

- Applied **Gaussian blur** to the above image:

[image]

- Now performed **DoG** with the above two images to obtain this: (I merely subtracted the two images above)

[image]

- Then I performed **Morphological operation** using the **ellipse kernel** to enhance the edge of the cell:

[image]

- To remove the unwanted speckles around the image I performed **median filtering** and finally obtained this:

[image]

You can refine this process to get an enhance image .

**EDIT:**

Here is the code I used:

```
import cv2

filename = 'Cell.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(filename)
cv2.imwrite('img.jpg',img)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imwrite('gray.jpg',gray)

bi = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray,7,75,75)
cv2.imwrite('bi.jpg',bi)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(bi,(3,3),0)
cv2.imwrite('blur.jpg',blur)
blur1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(bi,(17,17),0)
dog = blur1 - bi
cv2.imwrite('DoG.jpg',dog)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(5,5))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(dog, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, 13)
cv2.imwrite('close.jpg',close)

median = cv2.medianBlur(close,3)
cv2.imwrite('median.jpg',median)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Very impressive. I will appreciate a lot if you can share the code

Comment: Unfortunately I do not work with MATLAB. But just follow the steps as mentioned in the answer. You have built-in functions for all the above steps.

Comment: Is there a way to close the object in python-openCV so I can have the ellipsoid outlines? Thanks

Comment: I actually tried out **morphological close operation** but was not successful. You can check out [THIS PAGE](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#morphological-ops) for other options.

Comment: @user2788464 I woud also suggest doing some pre-processing to the image before trying the above code. Try *equalization* and *local adaptive histogram equalization*

Comment: Thanks. I will examine these options  but the thresholding options in Matlab were not successful. In general, I try to avoid morphological operation as I need the dimension of the cell.

Comment: @user2788464 Sure, give it a try and do post your results as well. :)

Comment: Jeru Luke I was looking again on the code and I noticed that you have blur and blur1, why?

Comment: Initially I thought of doing DoG using `blur` which had a kernel size of 3; the result was not so prominent. Then I used `blur1` which had a kernel size of 17; hence I was able to obtain better result. Try doing DoG for both  `blur1 - bi` and `blur - bi`; you will notice the difference