# Fill objects - openCV/Python

Tags: python, opencv

In the script based on [remove-noise-in-bw-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41776655/remove-noise-in-bw-image), I try to fill the object (The equivalent of imfill in Matlab) but without success. Can someone please explain me how to do so.

Script:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#image can be found in https://i.stack.imgur.com/afCDL.jpg
filename = 'E:/afCDL.jpg'

img = cv2.imread(filename)
cv2.imwrite('E:/img.jpg',img)
cv2.imshow("Original Image", img)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imwrite('E:/gray.jpg',gray)

bi = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray,5,25,25)

cv2.imwrite('E:/bi.jpg',bi)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(bi,(25,25),0)
cv2.imwrite('E:/blur.jpg',blur)
dog = blur - bi
cv2.imwrite('E:/DoG.jpg',dog)
cv2.imshow("DOG Image", dog)

kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
fill = cv2.morphologyEx(dog, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel) #Fill holes- DOES NOT WORK
cv2.imshow("Fill", fill)
removeNoise = cv2.morphologyEx(fill, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel) #Remove noise
cv2.imshow("remove Noise ", removeNoise)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try reading this [link](https://www.learnopencv.com/filling-holes-in-an-image-using-opencv-python-c/). I think it addresses the question.

This post [python-equivalent-to-matlab-funciton-imfill-for-grayscale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36294025/python-equivalent-to-matlab-funciton-imfill-for-grayscale) also has some pointers.

Comment: Upvote and Mark as correct the answer that works! Thanks

Comment: Tried to implemented both but they did not work as well.